# Button must get clicked after 5 mins even if app is closed

Tags: android, timer

I have one button on first page which takes to MainActivity page which has another button.I want the MainActivity page  button must be clickable after 15 mins only.15 mins must get started when Firstpage button is clicked.I want this to happen even if app is closed or in background so i am using sharedpreference.But problem is that MainActivity button is enabled as soon as i enter in it.Following is my code-

**First.java**

```
public class First extends Activity {
    Button btnnext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        btnnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CLicked now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", currentTime);
        editor.apply();
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }



    public void onRestart(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long previousTime = prefs.getLong("time", 0);
        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        if (currentTime - previousTime > 15*60*1000){
            //enable the button
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //disable it and start a new CountdownTimer; this is needed in order for
            //it to to become enabled if you're still in the app and the time ran out
            btn.setEnabled(false);
            new CountDownTimer(currentTime - previousTime, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    btn.setText("Timeover" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8B0000"));
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }.start();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you want this button to be clickable after even phone shut down? - forced ads man...

Comment: Yes want same even if app is running,or closed.

Comment: Can anyone give me example of countdown timer with Service?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the 'time' in shared preferences when the user click on the button in your `First` activity. Right now you store it in `onStop()` of your `MainActivity` which means that the first time your `onRestart()` code runs there is no 'time' value in shared preferences and thus your code thinks the 'previousTime' value is 0. Since you calculate `currentTime - previousTime` that will turn out to be longer than 15 minutes and you will enable the button.

**Update**

You just need to move the code to store the time in shared preferences from the `MainActivity` to the `First` activity. Do something like this: in the `onClick()` handler you store the time *and* start `MainActivity`. See the sample below:

**First.java**

```
public class First extends Activity {
    Button btnnext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        btnnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                storeTime();
                Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private void storeTime() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", currentTime);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i store it in shared pref?

Comment: Did changed but still button is clickable as i enter in MainActivity

Comment: Hmm, `onRestart` is only fired if your `MainActivity` goes through a configuration change. Try to replace the onRestart with `onStart`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement cron job for this condition.
you'll get reference from above link
http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=228

read carefully documentation this may help you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best and smooth way is to use local broadcast reciever and a service for timer.You can run your timer in the service and when the timer completes you can start a intent and send the intent data to press the button.performClick();

Comment: Is there any example of timer running in service?

Comment: If you want to run timer at background also then i think the service with async is the best way for the app performance.